# Scala: Why will a right folding on a List cause stack overflow whereas not for a left folding?

Tags: scala

I ran a right folding (:\) on a List of String, which caused a stack overflow. But When I changed it to use a left folding (/:), it worked fine. Why?

Comment: Incidentally, if you must fold from the right, consider reversing and folding from the left (then reversing again if necessary)--you use the heap instead of the stack that way (but it's slower for small lists).

Comment: @RexKerr On TraversableOnce, `def foldRight[B](z: B)(op: (A, B) => B): B = reversed.foldLeft(z)((x, y) => op(y, x))`.  Isn't there a heuristic to punt to /:?

Comment: Most of time, it makes no necessity to use right folding, so I can choose to use left folding safely. Thanks, guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Fold` are a general set of commonly used functions which traverse recursive data structures and typically result in a single value ([reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_%28higher-order_function%29)). On sequences and lists, FoldLeft (in a general sense) is tail-recursive and as such, it can be optimized. FoldRight is not tail-recursive and thus can not be tail-call optimized. It does potentially have the benefit of being able to be applied to infinite series however.

The implementation of `foldLeft` and `foldRight` from the scala libraries (pirated from @dhg's answer) reflect this optimization/lack-there-of. `foldLeft` has been manually tail-call optimized using a while loop. `foldRight` can not be.

```
override /*TraversableLike*/
def foldLeft[B](z: B)(f: (B, A) => B): B = {
  var acc = z
  var these = this
  while (!these.isEmpty) {
    acc = f(acc, these.head)
    these = these.tail
  }
  acc
}

override /*IterableLike*/
def foldRight[B](z: B)(f: (A, B) => B): B =
  if (this.isEmpty) z
  else f(head, tail.foldRight(z)(f))
```

I believe there is a section in [Programming in Scala, Second Edition by Odersky, Spoon, Venners](http://www.artima.com/shop/programming_in_scala_2ed) on folds which describes how `foldLeft` on Lists is tail-recursive while it may be possible to `foldRight` on infinite lists. Unfortunately, I do not have it on me at the moment in order to provide page numbers, etc. If not, it isn't very difficult to prove this.

See also the section of folds in [Learn You a Haskell for Great Good by Miran Lipovača](http://learnyouahaskell.com/higher-order-functions#folds)

> Back when we were dealing with recursion, we noticed a theme
>   throughout many of the recursive functions that operated on lists.
>   Usually, we'd have an edge case for the empty list. We'd introduce the
>   x:xs pattern and then we'd do some action that involves a single
>   element and the rest of the list. It turns out this is a very common
>   pattern, so a couple of very useful functions were introduced to
>   encapsulate it. These functions are called folds.

Comment: http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/working-with-lists.html#16.7 though maybe you mean it was improved for 2nd ed.

Comment: hrmmm, I don't see the part I'm thinking of. I read the 2nd edition, but I read it ~ 2 years ago, followed shortly by "Learn You a Haskell..." so it's possible I combined the two in my head.

Answer (score 10):

Since the source is open, you can actually see the implementations in [LinearSeqOptimized.scala](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/master/src/library/scala/collection/LinearSeqOptimized.scala#L103):

```
override /*TraversableLike*/
def foldLeft[B](z: B)(f: (B, A) => B): B = {
  var acc = z
  var these = this
  while (!these.isEmpty) {
    acc = f(acc, these.head)
    these = these.tail
  }
  acc
}

override /*IterableLike*/
def foldRight[B](z: B)(f: (A, B) => B): B =
  if (this.isEmpty) z
  else f(head, tail.foldRight(z)(f))
```

What you will notice is that `foldLeft` uses a while-loop while `foldRight` uses recursion.  The loop strategy is very efficient but recursion requires pushing a frame on the stack for every element in the list (as it traverses to the end).  This is why `foldLeft` works fine but `foldRight` causes a stack overflow.

Comment: Yes, it is. The list of strings only has 6000 more elements, a right folding then crashes a stack.